# Cassandra presto maven dependencies issues

Tags: maven, cassandra, dependencies, pom.xml, presto

i am trying to use cassandra 3.10 along with presto 0.162 in my project. i am stuck with maven dependencies in pom.xml. what would be the dependencies in pom.xml for cassandra 3.10 and presto 0.162.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.adejanovski</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-jdbc-wrapper</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.facebook.presto</groupId>
   <artifactId>presto-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>0.162</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: above is the code in pom.xml

Comment: am able to download all the dependencies you mentioned with just one warning `Overriding managed version 3.1.4 for cassandra-driver-core`. Is this bothering you?`

Comment: my project gets successful built after making changes in pom.xml but when i try to get any cassandra sesion or presto connection then it throws exception: exception.PrestoNetworkSocketException: java.net.SocketException and exception.CassandraConnectionException

Comment: can someone help in this?

Comment: okay, if you see an exception, add that stack trace to the question. That really helps

Comment: Having seen this `java.net.SocketException` , can you confirm if your cassandra is running?

Comment: yes, cassandra is performing other tasks at that time